# Inject angular2 component as child of directive

Tags: angular

As the title suggests i want to insert dynamically a component inside the element that belongs to a directive.

I have this:

```
<div *loadingSpinner="isLoading" class="page-banner banner-welcome">
  <h2>Welcome</h2>
</div>
```

And i'm adding the component like this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[loadingSpinner]"
})
export class LoadingSpinner implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    set loadingSpinner(showSpinner: boolean) {
        this.toggleSpinner(showSpinner);
    }
    private hostElement: any;
    private spinnerComponent: ComponentRef<LoadingSpinnerComponent>;
    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
                private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
                private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
        this.hostElement = templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        let componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(LoadingSpinnerComponent);
        this.spinnerComponent = this.viewContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);
    }
}
```

The result is my LoadingSpinnerComponent added after the element that contains the directive but i need it to be inside that element (after the  element)

Any ideas?